# How to give SQL access to NETWORK SERVICE account?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services, network-service

I am trying to create a schema and a table that is accessible by a Windows Service that I wrote, but my service is unable to gain access to it...

```
USE [tempdb]
GO

CREATE SCHEMA [blah]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [blah].[domains](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_domains] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

A very simple table.. When I try to `SELECT` it via my Windows Service, I'm getting:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'domains', database 'tempdb', schema 'blah'.

I've tried switching my Service account from `LocalService` to `NetworkService` but it gives the same thing.

The connection string I am using for my service:

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=tempdb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

I've also tried to create a new Logins for `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`, then a user `NETWORK SERVICE` mapped to that Login and then grant permission on `blah` as well as `domains` table, but still not working.

PS: The same code was able to access the table when I ran it as a normal executable, but not when is running as a `Service`.

Comment: I think when a windows service runs, it uses the same of the server concatenated with a '$' - so MyServer$ would be the login it uses when traversing your network (assuming the service and the database are on different servers).  Have you tried granting access to MyServer$, explicitly?

Comment: That is what I do - and it works for folder permissions as well as SQL permissions.

Comment: @StanShaw where/how can I do that? I don't see any option to grant that under my table nor user under SQL Management Studio when I check the table properties. How can I do that via a sql script?

Comment: In SSMS > Security > Logins....You'll have to navigate to the appropriate user in there - you will most likely need to add `Domain\NETWORK SERVICE` or `Domain\SYSTEM` or something like that.  I was wrong about the $ being available to SQL Server - that's only on file-level permissions.

Comment: Or you can easily configure your service to run as a windows account (which you can create, if necessary) - and then add that account as a SQL login - and provide whatever credentials are necessary.  I think that's your best bet, so I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: i used a lot NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE with MSSQL, so there shouldn't a problem. Just guessing: did you assigned server role (at least) public? BTW, be aware that tempdb can be recreated at restart. I believe it would better to create your table elsewhere.

Comment: If I set my table's permission to public, then it works. But I'm not sure if this is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

We discussed a few approaches in the comments, but I think your best bet is to:

- Create a Windows account (or use an existing one)
- Configure your service to run as that Windows account
- Add the Windows account as a SQL login
- Grant the desired permissions to that SQL login